# i have <a> links that were working but for some reason have stopped

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list in my HTML with 5 lists that all had  with links on them that were working fine. It was working fine until I added another unordered list, but i have no links inside it. I even gave it a separate class.

Here is my markup/CSS:

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    diplay: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 350px;
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right:45px;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover {
   font-weight:bold;
   color:grey;
}
a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage" >
    <img src="http://xoio.de/al_by_xoio1.jpg" alt="concert stadium" style="width:100%; position:absolute; padding-top:70px; height:930px"> 
    <div id="navBar">
        <div id="Logo">
            <h1 style="font-weight:bold;"> Ice Arena </h1>
        </div>
        <ul id="select">
            <li>
                <a style="color:#ffe700;" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Order Form</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The Arena</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've only added the code regarding the list and area of my problem.

Comment: Please use a formatter for your markup and CSS next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `ul`, otherwise other elements are above it and prevent the link behavior.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  diplay: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 350px;
  font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* added */
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: grey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage">
  <img src="http://xoio.de/al_by_xoio1.jpg" alt="concert stadium" style="width:100%; position:absolute; padding-top:70px; height:930px">
  <div id="navBar">
    <div id="Logo">
      <h1 style="font-weight:bold;">Ice Arena</h1>
    </div>
    <ul id="select">
      <li><a style="color:#ffe700;" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Order Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Arena</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i just did this and its not working. it must be something else in my code because it was working in the snippet

Comment: Indeed it is, if you share a broader snippet I can try to figure it there, otherwise it does the trick with the provided code. Try adding `z-index: 9999;` to the `ul` as well just in case (in addition to the relative position).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the CSS property (position:absolute;) in line 3.